# Wordpress ACF field into a stylesheet

Tags: php, css, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

So, i've set up a custom post type for theme settings, and a custom field edited from there for background color.

Script reads the style.php styles, unless i'm trying to get the field value.

Here is a piece of code I'm trying to make work

```
html, body {background-color:<?php the_field('page_background_color');?>;}
```

When looking at the source, background-color value is just blank.

Comment: I am assuming that value is added from the back end and you are trying to use that setting on the front end.Is it so?
If yes then have you wrote `<style>` tag in your file before writing above code ?

Comment: I've got this in the very beginning of the php style file <?phpheader("Content-type: text/css; charset: UTF-8");?>

Comment: Replace the lines that you entered with this one : `<?php
 $absolute_path = explode('wp-content', $_SERVER['SCRIPT_FILENAME']);
 $wp_load = $absolute_path[0] . 'wp-load.php';
 require_once($wp_load);

  /**
  Do stuff like connect to WP database and grab user set values
  */

  header('Content-type: text/css');
  header('Cache-control: must-revalidate');
?>`

Comment: Try putting a space between the `;` and `?>`

Answer (score 0):

When you work with the ACF Options Page you must user a string "options" as parameter for the function get_field() and the_field()

Try

```
html, body {background-color:<?php the_field('page_background_color', 'option' );?>;}
```

[ACF Options Documentation](http://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/how-to-get-values-from-an-options-page/)